# Codeigniter - show blank screen after adding comment in any method of controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

Codeigniter is showing blank page after adding comments in any method. eg add `//redirect('home');`  in controller index method. 
Also error reporting can not be enabled from index.php

but after enabling log errors i get this error in error_log file

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF) in /home/username/public_html/project/application/controllers/Home.php on line 1
```

here is my controller

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Home extends CI_Controller {

        public function index(){
            echo 'Home Page';
            //redirect('home');
        }
        public function test(){
            echo 'Test';
        }


    }
```

Comment: i think there is syntax error pls check your code.

Comment: after removing that comment then every thing is working.

Comment: nice but something wrong your code is proper pls put comment and check again

Comment: Do you calling `index action` with ajax?

Comment: no i am not using ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending hours and hours i figure out that there was some error on my FTP Client(**FileZilla**).

On uploading a file via **FileZilla** it convert all the code into one line therefor if there is any comments then shows error.

Answer (score -2):

Change first line to :

```
<?php 
     if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
         exit('No direct script access allowed');
```